# How do I create an alias for a directory in ipython?

Tags: ipython

On Windows I want to create an alias for my working directory so I can quickly cd into it.
I have tried this command

```
%alias $UWHPSC echo 'c:/Users/xxxx/Documents/uwhpsc'
cd $UWHPSC
```

which gives the following error

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: u'$UWHPSC'
c:\Users\xxxx\Documents\uwhpsc
```

Answer (score 3):

`%cd` has a notion of bookmarks, which persist across IPython sessions:

```
%bookmark UWHPSC c:/Users/xxxx/Documents/uwhpsc
%cd UWHPSC
```

See the output of `%bookmark?` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just define a normal Python variable, and then use it with a $ in the cd command:

```
UWHPSC = 'c:/Users/xxxx/Documents/uwhpsc'
cd $UWHPSC
```

Comment: once i close the ipython window or restart the kernel i will loose the link. I guess i can put this in the ipython startup

Comment: You can define it in a startup script, or use `%store`. But Min's solution is probably simpler.